# Running python 3.6 scripts in console

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm IDE to edit python 3.6 scripts and would like to run them in the console in order to look at system variables to debug. I'm used to the 2.7 interpreter and was able to run code in the console using the following command:

```
%run MyScript.py
```

The same command doesn't seem to work in a 3.6 console and I was not able to find a post answering this question. I'm relatively new to python and this should seem like something basic so maybe I've been searching posts with the wrong keywords. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `python3 MyScript.py` ?

Comment: It is good that you mention the version numbers, because there are definitely things in Python2 which have become changed or deprecated in Python3 so code meant to run in Python2 would not necessarily run in Python3. Without seeing the `MyScript.py` contents , and the 3.6 console error, there is no way to be sure if that is the issue.

Comment: i do `py -3.6 MyScript.py` for python3.6 and `py -3.5 MyScript.py` for python3.5 .  hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Clarity. Thank you for pointing out the missing information. The error given is a 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' pointing to the '%' sign in '%run MyScript.py', so I assume it's not related to the content of the script. I'll try the same thing on a very simple script as well.

Answer (score 0):

After learning more about the `%run` function I realized that it is not inherent to python but is a 'magic command' (which all start with `%`) belonging to the ipython module. After installing ipython with pip for the 3.6 interpreter using `pip install ipython`, the `%run` command I had trouble with now executes successfully as it does in 2.7 after restarting the IDE. I guess ipython was already installed for the 2.7 interpreter I was using but didn't realize it. Thank you all for your help in finding the solution.